# Rails 3: Escape characters (\) appearing in part of JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, object-graph

Anyone know why some of my json elements are being backslash(`\`) escaped while others are not?

```
{"first":"John","last":"Smith","dogs":"[{\"name\":\"Rex\",\"breed\":\"Lab\"},{\"name\":\"Spot\",\"breed\":\"Dalmation\"},{\"name\":\"Fido\",\"breed\":\"Terrier\"}]"}
```

Ideally I'd like NONE of them to be escaped...

This was generated by overriding `as_json` in two models. Person has_many Dogs.

```
#models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs

  def as_json(options={}) 
     {
       :first => first,
       :last => last,
       :dogs => dogs.to_json
     }
   end
end

#models/dog.rb
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :people

  def as_json(options={})
    {
      :name => name, 
      :breed => breed
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the `to_json` on `dogs.to_json`.

Comment: **BINGO!** Thanks! You understand why that happened? cuz I don't...still too green.

Comment: By calling to_json on dogs you were re-encoding it and the second encoding caused the escaping.

Comment: I couldn't make this work -- removing `to_json` resulted in the `inspect` string being returned for each `Dog`. But this approach worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170372/serializing-and-deserializing-complex-rails-objects-with-json/4170710#4170710

Comment: @zetetic: It definitely works for Rails 3. Is that what version you're using?

Comment: Rails 3.0.1, Ruby 1.9.2. If I understand correctly it *ought* to work as you describe, that is it should call `as_json` on the associations. Maybe something is borked in my environment.

Comment: @zetetic: Yeah, I'm not really sure what to tell you, but I just tested it on my Rails 3 app and it worked perfectly respecting the as_json definitions of both models.

Answer (score 12):

Check out jonathanjulian.com's [Rails to_json or as_json](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/)?